# Converting Date in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Snowflake Stored Proc that uses Run_Date as a parameter. With the the code when I use the this date I get Tue May 03 2022 08:37:42 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time).
How can I convert this date to something like this - 2022-01-15 10:20:33.001 +0000

Comment: What language are you using for your stored procedure? Is this JavaScript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Snowflake datetime conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72104781/snowflake-datetime-conversion)